Three Men's Morris ordered variant with FIFO pieces
I had an electronic game several decades ago where I could play Three Men's Morris. After placing three pieces, I would click on one free spot and my earliest-placed token would move there; the computer would do the same. A player wins when three pieces form a row.

The difference from Three Men's Morris: in Three Men's Morris, after three turns, I can move any piece. In this variant, I have to move them in the order I placed them.

I've been looking for the name of this game. I started with tic-tac-toe, then I realized that Three Men's Morris is the name when pieces are placed again. I searched for "ordered", "numbered" and first-in-first-out (FIFO) and could not find it.
In Wikipedia, the game is called Extended tic-tac-toe:

like the three men's morris game, each player has three pieces, but when moving pieces, players must first move their first pieces, then the second pieces, then the third pieces, then the first pieces, and so on. This game is harder than both tic-tac-toe and three men's morris, but the first player has a way to win by taking the edge first. Alternatively, by taking the center or corner first, the game will be drawn.

But when I search for "extended tic-tac-toe" online, I don't find this game, only tic-tac-toe with larger boards, several boards, or 3D versions.
Does this variant of Three Men's Morris have a specific name?

What you are describing sounds exactly like Three Men's Morris.  What part of this game is different from Three Men's Morris?

Sounds a bit like this https://www.whatdowedoallday.com/nine-holes-game/

@Zags In Three Men's Morris, after three turns, I can move any piece. In this variant, I have to move them in the order I placed them.

@Zibelas Yes, it's similar, except that in my variant, we have to move the pieces in the order they were placed. I checked the other games linked at the bottom of the post and they are different from this variant.

Do you remember if the game had diagonal lines?

@KMR I cannot remember, I think not. The rules of the game allowed diagonal lines: if I had three pieces on a diagonal, I would win.

If you are looking to play the game online, I made a web based implementation. You can play against an AI or another human in the same computer at https://alijdens.github.io/three-tac-toe/

